# Site Template won't show up on publishing site when creating a site

Tags: publishing, site-template, collaboration

I have a site template and I was able to deploy it to the farm. I can see the template when I create a site from a team site. I don't even see that option when I create a site from publishing site. What should I do so that site template will appear in the publishing site as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site Actions > Site Settings > Page layouts and site templates (under Look and Feel)

Subsite Templates: make sure your site template is selected

Comment: Are you SP guru or something. Thanks for you help. Just found this link as well if someone needs step by step process. Thanks again. http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-site-templates-not.html